Grok filter for the message log
I have a message log as below
"Jul 11, 2022 6:44:49 AM org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTrustManagerFactorySpi getDefaultTrustStore
INFO: Initializing with trust store at path: /app/ctrlm-agent/ctm/cm/AFT/JRE_11/lib/security/cacerts"
I need to filter Loglevel: INFO / message "org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTrustManagerFactorySpi getDefaultTrustStore" / and the rest. Please help check my Grok below and give me advice
(?%{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY:day}, %{YEAR:year} (?%{TIME} AM|PM))) %{LOGLEVEL:severity} %{GREEDYDATA:message}
Thanks all
My Grok (?%{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY:day}, %{YEAR:year} (?%{TIME} AM|PM))) %{LOGLEVEL:severity} %{GREEDYDATA:message}
